# Cannot remove last Point from Cloned Geometry in OpenLayers (in DynamicMeasure.js Control)

Tags: openlayers-2

I am working with OpenLayers-2 and currently can't figure out why I cannot remove the last Point from a cloned LineString-geometry.

This is my original geometry, a LineString with three points and the last point:

```
geometry: LINESTRING(594281.087 5892671.049,594320.061 5892645.758, 594324.266 5892644.357)
point: POINT(594324.266 5892644.357)  //the last point in the LineString
```

Now I want to remove the last point in this linestring to measure the length of the reduced linestring. But when I clone this geometry and remove the latest point, then the cloned Geometry is still the same. But removeComponent works when I use it on the original Geometry.

```
var oGeom2 = geometry.clone();
var bCheckA = oGeom2.removeComponent( point );
```

The result is:

```
bCheckA:true 
oGeom2: LINESTRING(594281.087 5892671.049,594320.061 5892645.758, 594324.266 5892644.357)
```

But when I remove the latest point from the "geometry" Object, then it works:

```
var bCheckB = geometry.removeComponent( point );
bCheckB: true
geometry:LINESTRING(594281.087 5892671.049,594320.061 5892645.758)
```

What is the error here? Do I need a Timeout after .clone() or something like that?

*Background: I am using the OpenLayers DynamicMeasure.js library in combination with Snapping-Control. When a Vertex or point was found, this Point is added to the line onClick but also another point which may be only centimeters away from the Snap-Point. Therefore I need to remove this last point to get correct measurements.*

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem emerges from somewhere else. The clone() works fine, also the measure and the removeComponent. But I guess that the code e.g. in Measure.js makes other adjustments while continuing measuring that mess up my geometry.

In OpenLayers.Control.Measure in the `measurePartial` function the geometry is cloned again: `geometry = geometry.clone();`. And when I tried to add the point using `geometry.addPoint(point);` then the point-geometry sometimes already changed.

Therefore I try a completely different approach than continue to find the solution there.